# Unhealthy web role instance in azure cloud service deployment

Tags: azure, certificate, instance, azure-configuration

My web role instance can't run after the deployment to azure, it tries to start it and then it reports the instance as "Unhealthy" and gives the following message: "The role could not be started (Role could not be started. System is initializing." (under the instances tab on azure site)

I have recently added a certificate and set up the config files following this guide http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/

So I'm guessing that my configuration files are fine, also because when they aren't it raises an error before the deployment begins. Before the new certificate the deployments were just fine though.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how could I trace the problem to see where it fails?

Comment: What happens if you remove the cert that was recently added?

Comment: I tried removing the SSL certificate and also the endpoint and the webrole could start properly, but I will need to access via https and use that certificate. May it be something wrong with the certificate? should I try to get a new one?

Comment: You can enable intellitrace on a deployment and then use Server Explorer in Visual Studio to download the Intellitrace logs. Also when you publish you can enable RDP access and connect to the machine and poke around. When I've had trouble those two things have been life savers.

Comment: Has the SSL cert thumbprint been added to the configuration file (.cscfg I believe), and also uploaded to the Cloud Service?